# Angular - Custom validator function in the controller: How to access 'this'?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a custom validator for a form in Angular. It would be perfect if I could access the `this` of the controller, but it's undefined in the validator function.

This is my validator function:

```
validateSuccessShortName(control: AbstractControl) {
      //can't read this.randomProp, because this is undefined
      if (control.value.length > this.randomProp.length) {
        return {value: control.value};
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Here is a [***STACKBLITZ***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tqp9o1?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) demonstrating the issue.

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply impossible in the Angular framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tqp9o1?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts

And for future improvements way better move all validation in another file, and first params for each function must be config. You validators must not dependents from `this` just from config object

Just change on `this.validateSuccessShortName.bind(this)`, because you function missing context

```
shortName: new FormControl('', [
        this.validateSuccessShortName.bind(this)
])
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept this answer when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

Your angular validator doesn't reference your component property. To fix this you need to bind `this` to the validator.

```
export class HomePage {
    private arr: Array<any>;
    private thevalue: string;
    public thisForm: FormGroup;
    public randomProp: string;
  constructor(
    private modal: ModalController,
    public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.thevalue = "Initial value";
    this.randomProp = "This is a random property";
    this.thisForm = new FormGroup({
      shortName: new FormControl('', [
        this.validateSuccessShortName.bind(this)
      ])
    });
  }
  validateSuccessShortName(control: AbstractControl) {
      if (control.value.length > this.randomProp.length) {
        return {value: control.value};
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```